# Auto create google groups from sheets

Tags: google-apps

Searched the net, youtube, and google forums/documentation but can't seem to find this one even if it is possible.

I'm using a google form as a starting point for a workflow that then gets turned into a google group. Is there any scripts that can auto create a google group from the google forms output in sheets once form is submitted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that but didn't think it was the magic code. I'm going to try and mess with that and see if I can make it work. Will post update.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, so just give it a try. This is what I've found. Directory API let's you [create a group](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups) by making a POST URI request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups
```

with request body:

```
{
    "email": "sales_group@example.com",
    "name": "Sales Group",
    "description": "This is the Sales group."
}
```

Since you are using Google Forms, the option would be to use AppScript to perform the XHR request.

Try to make use of [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) in Appscript.
var options =

```
{
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com/upload_form.cgi", options);
```